# JQuery .click suddenly broken

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I had some jquery code in my php project that was working great... and now it isn't.  I'm not sure what I changed and have double checked that the CSS is correct as I can manually change display away from "none" and it works. I also know JQUERY is working because other elements from the same document are functioning. Am I missing something simple?

Here is the relevant code:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#addq_btn, div.darken').click(function() {
    $('div#addq_lb').toggle(250);
    $('div.darken').toggle(0);
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="question_btn" id="addq_btn" >Add Question</a>

<div class="darken"></div>

<div class="lightbox" id="addq_lb">
    <h3>Enter a new question below.</h3>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <textarea name="question" required="required" 
                  maxlength="150"></textarea><br /> 
    <input class="btn" type="submit" 
                  name="questionsubmit" value="Add Question">
</form>
<button class="btn" id="addq_btn">Cancel</button>
<br /><br />
<p id="smallinfo">You can add answers on this 
page after you've added the question.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked your console? does it say there's an error?  have you tried writing an `alert("TEST");` in your document.ready and your element.click?

Comment: Your JS code is not even in a script tag.

Comment: Sorry the JS is in a separate .js file, should have specified that.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: It would be much more useful for you, and for us if you made a stripped down use case in jsFiddle or something. There are tons of stuff going on in this code, and to be sure you are looking in the right direction, you need to pair down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a the id duplicated, "addq_btn" so that causes the conflict and jquery can not respond to the event, the id must be unique in the dom, try changing the id of the button i supossed, besides i recomend to you use .on('click', function(){}).

Comment: Why would using the `on` function be better than the `click` shorthand?

Comment: hello, using .click is almost the same as using .on, the diference is with using .on, you can asign the same handler to multiples elements. for example <div id="content">
    <a href="#">linka</a>
    <a href="#">linkb</a>
    <a href="#">linkc</a>
</div> then you can asign the handler to all a, $("#content").on("click", "a", function() {
    
    // $(this) point to the  <a> who has trigger the event.
});

Comment: `click` will also assign the handler to all the elements in the selector though.

Comment: ok, another plus it is valid for elements who does not exist yet on the dom. when you generate the elements with an ajax call for example.

Comment: That is simply not true. Only existing elements can have handlers assigned. After adding new elements, the handler has to be assigned again, either through `click` or `on`. See http://jsfiddle.net/Z8MpS/

Answer (score 1):

There are two elements with the ID `addq_btn`. IDs should be unique and JQuery treats them so. Does changing one of the `addq_btn` IDs solve this issue?

If you want these elements to be used equally based on a certain selector, I would recommend using a shared class instead, as they are made to be re-used by several elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well... this is very strange.  I started testing, cutting and pasting back in parts of the code exactly as they were, and now it's working... with no changes from me. maybe a weird space character somewhere or something.  Either way it's working again.  Thanks for all your help... sorry if this is the most useless StackOverflow answer ever.